# How can I test the input handling of my LibGDX videogame?

Tags: java, input, automated-tests, libgdx, lwjgl

I am developing a videogame in java using LibGDX, but the problem would remain also for a general-purpose application. I want to test how my game reacts to a given sequence of inputs (from keyboard, mouse or a controller). Specifically, I just implemented a couple of splash screens: the first one displays the LibGDX logo, the second one is a "A game by xxxxx" screen. Both the splash screens take 0.5 seconds to fade-in, then wait 2 seconds, then fade-out in 0.5 seconds. I added the possibility to press Enter on the keyboard to skip each splash screen, to arrive faster at the main menu.

So the tests I am trying to implement are the following three:

- right after launch, with no input, the app shows the `LogoSplashScreen`
- after pressing Enter one time, the app shows the `PresentationSplashScreen`
- after pressing Enter two times, the app shows the `MainMenuScreen`

Unfortunately, I can't find anything that works for this purpose.

I want to specify that the application already does what is required. My question, in short, is "How can I automate these manual tests?".

1. I tried using the `java.awt.Robot` class which generates (quoted from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html)) *native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed.*
   It worked really well with detecting actual pixel colors, but the KeyEvents generated from it somehow do not reach my application.
2. I tried using the [`InputEventQueue`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/latest/com/badlogic/gdx/InputEventQueue.html) by feeding it all the events and then calling `drain` on my app's `InputProcessor`. I haven't actually given up on this one since its problem is that I cannot test my Lwjgl3Application if the constructor starts to run the main loop in the same thread. I also tried by wrapping the call to the constructor inside a Thread but I still cannot know when the app has started "looping".
3. Many others who had a similar problem in the past received the suggestion to use the [`GdxTestRunner`](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-testing/blob/master/tests/src/de/tomgrill/gdxtesting/GdxTestRunner.java), so I tried it. I discovered that, since it "wraps" your application with an headless one (by mocking the Lwjgl backend), it doesn't actually change the screens because it has no access to the graphics.

Comment: I suspect you're running your app full screen. A Java Robot has to be in the foreground to work, so you may have better luck running in a window.

Comment: For tests and development, the app runs in windowed mode. Only in production it runs in full screen.